# JSON API - IONIC (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm extracting a JSON API URL in the framework ionic with AngularJs like the code below:

```
.factory('BuyApi', function($http) {
  var obj = {};

  obj.buy = function() {
    var api = "https://maiscarrinho.com/api/search?q=gato&pageNumber=0&pageSize=10";
    return $http.get(api);
  };
  return obj
})

.controller('MainControl', function($scope, BuyApi){

  $scope.produtos;

  BuyApi.buy().success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      $scope.produtos = data.results;
  })
});
```

For the JSON file I use this URL: [https://maiscarrinho.com/api/search?q=gato&pageNumber=0&pageSize=10](https://maiscarrinho.com/api/search?q=gato), but every time you do an refresh on the page data changes (more exactly the prices) and it does not happen in the actual site : https://maiscarrinho.com/search?q=gato.

So I did an investigation might it be because the request and response header? Do I need to pass parameter? or something?

Comment: It seems that on main page they are sorted the items by some field.

Comment: it don't seem like it, because it can't be sorted only by price i think. all the order aspects or rigth only the prices are changed.

Comment: that's the provider code: [https://maiscarrinho.com/api/provider/portugal] (https://maiscarrinho.com/api/provider/portugal)

Comment: It seems your problem is not with headers, neither with the code you have posted. Do you ever make a xhr call to 'https://maiscarrinho.com/api/...' after the page loads? The data you see on the page come as HTML, from the first request. Try to add `console.log(data)` after `BuyApi.buy().success(function(data) {` and you won't probably see anything in the console since the call won't be made. Maybe your application does not initialise properly?

Comment: @Matej P. i do retrive the data sucessfull, that's not the problem. the problem is that the json file when refresh in chrome or other IE will change the data for no appearnt reason

Comment: Oh, i thought you wanted the prices to change. Still, the problem is not with the code you shared but with the api. It is broken on the actual site as well. Just try to check and uncheck 'Em promoção' couple of times. You will see that every time the prices are different. The reason why this doesn't happen when refreshing the actual site is, that it doesn't fetch data from the api on the first load, but rather it comes in html form. So definitely something going on with the API.

Comment: @Matej P i tried viewing some code and i thing there is a security in api that changes the prices can you help me crack this